# Electron app not getting installed after quitandinstall function

Tags: angular, electron, nsis, electron-builder, electron-updater

I am using electron auto updater to get my app updated whenever a new version is available. I am using aws as my generic provider. The problem i am facing is the app detects a new version and download it successfully but when i call quitAndInstall() function the app quits but never gets installed. The installation popup fills half way and suddenly dissapears and then nothing happens.

I tried putting my quitAndInstall() in try catch block but there is no error.
I even tried putting my quitAndInstall() in setTimeout but seems like nothing is working!
Can someone help!

Comment: Anybody looking for a solution to this, i got the solution
After trying for few days I found that there was no issue with the auto updater instead it was the issue with the file name I was uploading on my server. Make sure your exe file name for every new version is different otherwise it will not install after auto update. For eg. setup_0.0.1.exe than your next version file should be setup_0.0.2.exe Make sure to update the file name in latest.yml and blockmap file as well.